# Segmentation fault in "for loop" in C

Tags: c, file

The code below read from file .

I have a function which creates an offset and read no_of_bytes after that named "readit"

The code is working fine when I am not using for loop or not using

no_of_sensor=*p;
iteration=*p;

At any time I can either use for loop or the above statements. When both are used in a single .c file it gives segmentation fault.

But I am not able to find where is it accessing ROM.
Kindly help me to debug it with some explanations.

Thank you
'''

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void readit(uint8_t *p, int offset,int no_of_elements ,FILE *fp,uint8_t no_of_bytes)

{

     fseek(fp,offset,SEEK_SET);
    fread(p,no_of_bytes,no_of_elements,fp);
}

int main()

{

    int i;
    FILE *fp;
    uint8_t size,no_of_sensors,iterations,no_of_bytes;
    uint8_t *p;
    uint16_t *vals;
    double *dis;



    fp=fopen("data.txt","rb");
    readit(p,1,1,fp,1);
    iterations=*(p);
    readit(p,0,1,fp,1);
    no_of_sensors=*p;

    printf("iterations %d no of sensors %d\n",iterations,no_of_sensors);

    vals=(uint16_t*)calloc(no_of_sensors,sizeof(uint16_t));
    dis=(double*)calloc(no_of_sensors,sizeof(double));

    printf("Hii");

    for ( i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        printf("HII");
    }

    fclose(fp);


    free(dis);
    free(vals);
    return 0;
}
```

'''

Comment: You want to store the read values in `iterations` and `no_of_sensors`, then you just pass the address of those variables directly. No need for the variable `p`. And if you read stuff in the correct order, then there is no need for `fseek` either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fread receive a buffer, so p can be an array, not a simple pointer.

aka p must point to an allocated area, either by stack:

uint8_t p[5];

or by heap:

uint8_t p = malloc(5);

if by heap must be freed later on.

Comment: The code is working after changing pointer to arrray but ,in fread                              Syntax:-  `fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)`  .  The website I took from says the ** ptr should point to a block of memory of size nmemb .**                            
 In my code I am declaring *p so it has 1 byte of memory allocated and I am passing 1 for nmemb. And why if I don't use for loop the code is working fine I can print anything but point where I add for loop it is giving error. Could you please help me understand the error better. Thank you in advance

Comment: You declared *p, it is a pointer, you did not initialize it, so it contain garbage, the fact the program does not crash currently is by chance (the garbage is actually pointing at something valid, but this is by chance). It does not have 1 byte allocated, it is a pointer.

Comment: A pointer contain an address, that's all. An array declaration tells the compiler to allocate area on the stack so the array will point to an allocated area.